# Reusable Angular Material mat-chip-list input with email validation

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field, mat-input

I need a reusable `mat-chip-list` input, which knows the following: can type anything in the input, but only valid email addresses can be added to the chip list. If the input has an invalid email in it and user presses `ENTER`, `COMMA` or `TAB`, then the input value cannot be added to the list and the `mat-form-field` should have an error.

I have a working example, but that's not reusable as `mat-form-field`'s input and I need to copy-paste it every time I want to use it :(

I am open to any ideas how to solve the problem, I tried to invoke an error in the `mat-form-field` from the custom input (which is not nice, I know) and I tried to create a special validator for the `mat-form-field`, but it also failed.

I'm using Angular 9.1.12 & Angular Material 9.2.4.

Here is an example for a the new reusable, but not working component and the not reusable but working component:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-chip-list-email-input

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to make it work: I put an `ngModel` on the `mat-chip-list` input with email validator and when the user wants to add anything to the input, I check if the `ngModel` is valid. When not valid, I won't add the input value to the list and if the custom input is used in a form, I invoke an error in the outer `mat-form-field`. Not the best solution, so I'm open to an other ideas.

I also used extra validator on the `mat-form-field`, so if the list contains a invalid email, it will throw validation error.

You can find the solution in the stackblitz above.